# Re-expressing this as a convex optimization problem.

Tags: convex-optimization

For some $n$, $\vec{\tau}^{\min},\vec{\tau}^{\max}, \vec{d} \succcurlyeq 0$, and convex,non-decreasing and positive $\Phi(s) : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, I have the following optimization program:
\begin{align*}
&\min \sum_{i=1}^n \tau_i \Phi(s_i) \\
&\text{Subject to: } \forall i,\\
& s_{\min} \le s_i \le s_{\max} \\
& \tau^{\min}_i \le \tau_i \le \tau^{\max}_i \\
& \tau_i s_i = d_i
\end{align*}
My goal is to convert this into a convex optimization problem. Would appreciate any help on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see. All variables are nonnegative. First eliminate $\tau_i$:
\begin{align*}
\min \quad& \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d_i}{s_i} \Phi(s_i) \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & \forall i,\\
&s_{\min} \le s_i \le s_{\max} \\
&\tau^{\min}_i s_i \le d_i \le \tau^{\max}_i s_i \\
& s_i \geq 0
\end{align*}
then substitute $x_i = 1/s_i$:
\begin{align*}
\min \quad& \sum_{i=1}^n d_i x_i \Phi(1/x_i) \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & \forall i,\\
&s_{\min} x_i \le 1 \le s_{\max} x_i \\
&\tau^{\min}_i \le d_i x_i \le \tau^{\max}_i \\
& x_i \geq 0
\end{align*}
Et voila, it is convex.